# Textview Adapter doesnt work

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to use adapter in a textview. i'm using this code:

```
var textview1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.categorytext);
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
textview1.Adapter = adapter;
```

I get an error 'TextView' does not contain a definition for 'Adapter' and no extension method 'Adapter' accepting a first argument of type 'TextView' could be found.

Comment: Your error is telling you that you can't use an 'Adapter' with a 'TextView'. 'TextView' does not have an extension method to include an adapter as its data feed. So, use something else instead of an adapter. For example a spinner.

Answer (score 0):

To create items for Spinner, you need to have an adapter.

```
 var items = new List<string>() {"hp", "mac", "lenovo"};
    var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, items);
```

After setting an `adapter` you need to find the `Spinner` in your view and set to the `adapter` like

```
var spin = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner1);
spin.Adapter = adapter;
```

Comment: sorry you can't add a list item in TextView so you need to add a ListView instead of TextView

Comment: I want to make a combobox (like spinner). Can i do this with Listview?

Comment: Also i cant insert listview'text neither. (cause there is no definition)

Comment: I think you need to use Spinner in that case

Comment: Just see my code is very simple:SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into customers (name) values '" + spinner1.Text + "'", con); (but i have error there is no definition for Text)

Comment: @user6453809 Did you forget to instantiate the view contains the `Spinner`?

Comment: How i will do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117524/discussion-between-madhab-dhakal-and-user6453809).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an Adapter in a TextView because it does not contain functions to take in an Adapter as a data feed.

To use an adapter to feed data to a view, there are many options.

You can use a spinner or a listview in your case.

Hope that helps as an answer to your question! :)